# Compiling C code in Linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, execution

I am using Linux mint 16. I had a code that I change it a bit.
I use two following commands in terminal in order to run the code. The problem is that it does not give me any error but the changes are not applied, which means it runs the previous version of code.

```
gcc -std=c99 -c Code.c -o Code.o
./Code
```

Comment: `gcc -std=c99 Code.c`, `./a.out`

Comment: Instead of running ./Code, try running ./Code.o.

Comment: you're compiling. but not linking and creating executables

Answer (score 2):

`gcc -std=c99 -c Code.c -o Code.o` will put the compiled object file in `Code.o`, not `./Code` as you expect it to be..

Also, `-c` tells do not run the linker. So effectively you end up with an object file which cannot be run.

`gcc -std=c99 Code.c -o Code` will produce what you need.

For a complete list of `gcc` flags either use `man gcc` or see http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

Comment: thank you for your complete explanation. Do you know any website that state all the c commands?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gcc -std=c99 -c Code.c -o Code
./Code
```